# How to attach Write node to Read node?

Tags: python, nuke

Well, I've just started getting into Nuke's API. Here I import the footage:

```
nuke.nodes.Read(file="E:/Final/Practice/MVI_8411.mov", name="Footage")
```

selected the footage (and stored in a variable):

```
footage = nuke.toNode("Footage")
```

When I pipe it to Write node, it doesn't work:

```
nuke.createNode("Write")
```

I create a Write node though, but it's not connected to Read node. I expected it to connect. Doesn't `toNode()` function selects nodes in *non-GUI* mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay particular attention to classes of nodes and their names in Node Graph. In the following example `Read` is a class, `Read1` is a name.

So try this script to get your `Write` node connected:

```
import nuke as nk
import nukescripts

nk.nodes.Read(file="E:/Final/Practice/MVI_8411.mov")
nk.toNode("Read1").setSelected(True)
nk.createNode("Write")
nukescripts.connect_selected_to_viewer(0)
```

or this way:

```
import nuke as nk
import nukescripts    

nk.createNode("Read", "file E:/Final/Practice/MVI_8411.mov name footage")
nk.toNode("footage").setSelected(True)
nk.createNode("Write")
nukescripts.connect_selected_to_viewer(0)
```

To find out what the class a node belongs to, create, for example, a `CheckerBoard`, select it and press <kbd>i</kbd> shortcut on your keyboard. You'll see its class is `CheckerBoard2` and its name is `CheckerBoard1`.

[image]

And in case you use a node of `class 2` your lines should look like this:

```
nk.createNode("CheckerBoard2")
nk.toNode("CheckerBoard1").setSelected(True)
nk.createNode("Write")
```

Or your syntax would be like this:

```
nk.nodes.CheckerBoard2(name="board")
nk.toNode("board").setSelected(True)
nk.createNode("Write")
```

...or just like that:

```
nk.createNode("CheckerBoard2", "name board")
nk.toNode("board").setSelected(True)
nk.createNode("Write")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
readNode = nuke.nodes.Read( file = "E:/Final/Practice/MVI_8411.mov", name = "Footage" )    
nuke.nodes.Write( inputs = [ readNode ] )
```

You can also put the `nuke.nodes.Read` statement directly between the `[]` to avoid the temporary variable. It just looks more clean like this.